# How do I concatenate an integer onto a string in C?

Tags: c, int, concatenation

The part of the code in question is attempting to decode what register is being used by a MIPS instruction.

This does it by passing in an integer value of the register and then should return a string containing the name of the register. The prince statement that does it is here, where it calls getReg to get the string.

```
printf("$%d aka $%s\n", itype->rs, getReg(itype->rs));
```

So far, I've tried this to concatenate them (without the case statements):

```
char* getReg(int d) {
  char out[4];
  sprintf(out, "a%d", (d - 4));
  return out;
}
```

But the output results in this:

> $6 aka $ìü(

When it should be:

> $6 aka $a2

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Whether `out` is large enough is irrelevant, returning a local array is still undefined behavior.

Comment: True, try to give a `printf` after your `sprintf` and see. Also, use the GDB, helps a lot

Answer (score 4):

You are returning address of a local variable (`out`).

```
char* getReg(int d) {
 char out[4];
 sprintf(out, "a%d", (d - 4));
 return out;
}
```

scope and life of `out` is within function `getReg()`  only.

Allocate memory dynamically for `out` to return and access outside function. (*and large enough*), like below

```
#define SIZE 25
char* getReg(int d) {
     char *out = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
     sprintf(out, "a%d", (d - 4));   // I don't know about calculation??
      return out;
}
```

and don't forget to free memory.

Comment: 1. it should be `char *out`, 2. `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for `char* out`. And yes `sizeof(char)` is `1` but I always do this way :)

Answer (score 0):

The array `out` is local to your `getreg` function; once the function exits, `out` no longer exists and the pointer value you return is no longer valid.

It's better to pass the output array as a parameter to the function:

```
void getReg(int d, char *str)
{
  sprintf(str, "a%d", (d-4));
}
```

and call it as

```
char mystr[4];
getReg(r, mystr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others the OP returns a reference to storage, which is already invalid if used in the call to `printf()`.

An alternative to provide an external buffer whould be this:

```
char * getReg(int d, char * out) 
{
  sprintf(out, "a%d", (d - 4));

  return out;
}

...

printf(
  "$%d aka $%s\n", 
  itype->rs,  
  getReg(
    itype->rs, 
    (char[32]){0} /* provide a 32 byte long buffer, initialised to 0s */
  )
);
```